# Setting constraint to inActive keeps breaking it

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, nslayoutconstraint, uideviceorientation

I want to switch between 2 constraints when device orientation changed. But even if I set the `isActive` to `false`, systems keeps showing me the `Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.` warning and I lost one of those constraints for the whole app life cycle.

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
        iPadPortraintWidthConstraint.isActive = false
        iPadLandscapeWidthConstraint.isActive = true
    } else {
        iPadLandscapeWidthConstraint.isActive = false
        iPadPortraintWidthConstraint.isActive = true
    }        
}
```

What should be done here?

Comment: Copy paste your error. And show your constraint set up code.

Comment: The error is unable to satisfy those two constraints (system consider both of them active eventhough I set one of them to inactive).

Comment: When you set a constraint to inactive, it is removed, so you will need to re-add it as well as making it active.

Comment: ohh, I think this may be the issue. SO set it to inActive = removing the constraint?